# Не переключается раскладка в консоли Linux Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, консоль

В самой консоли не переключается язык ввода на русский, всегда печатается на английском языке. Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить мою проблему?

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Localization

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.